# A shaped pulse as a sum of rectangular pulses

Tags: hamiltonian, time-evolution, radio-frequency, bloch-sphere

I have a pulse with lineshape

$L(ω)=\frac{1}{π}\frac{\frac{1}{2}Γ}{((ω−ω_0)^2+(\frac{1}{2}Γ)^2)}$

in the frequency domain where $\Gamma$ is the pulse width and $\omega_0$ is the resonant frequency of the pulse. I want to model the effect of this pulse on a Bloch vector. I have tried decomposing the pulse into a series of rectangular pulses of different amplitudes. The Hamiltonian for a single rectangular pulse along the $z$ axis is

$H=-\omega (\cos(\phi)\sigma_x + \sin(\phi)\sigma_y)$

where $\omega$ is the amplitude of the pulse, $\phi$ is the phase of the pulse and $\sigma_i$ are the Pauli matrices. The time evolution operator for this pulse is given by

$U=e^{-iHt}$

where $t$ is the pulse width in the time domain.

I require a pulse with $\Gamma=5$MHz, $\omega_0=97.5$MHz, which gives the graph in the figure below.

[image]

I want to split this into a series of rectangular pulses, each of width $0.5$MHz. The pulse width is $5$MHz, (from $95-100$MHz) which corresponds to $200$ns in the time domain, but the tails of the pulse stretch infinitely. I want to take these tails into account over the range shown in the figure but I'm unsure how this affects the pulse width - do I define a larger pulse width or keep the width the same but analyse the tails as separate pulses outside of this pulse width?

As well as this, I want to consider Bloch vectors that are off-resonant from this pulse (i.e. their resonant frequency is not $97.5$MHz). My initial thought is that whichever rectangular segment the vector is on resonance with acts on the vector and rotates it accordingly for the short amount of time that particular pulse acts for. Is this correct or will the neighbouring rectangular pulses also affect the state?